# Node js - How to use connection variable

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a database connection structure that allow multi database connections but I'm having problems about saving the connection so I can use in `mssql.request()`.

I login form the user has to choose which database wants to use, so I'm thinking in trigger the select box database with this code that works fine.

**LoginController.js**

```
setDB: (req, res) =>
  {
    var connection = db.setDB(req.params.dbname);
    connection.then(result => {
      res.send(result);
    });
  },
```

**db.setDB**

```
const mssql = require('mssql');

module.exports =
{
  setDB: (req, res) =>
  {
    console.log('Prepare to connect to ' + req);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
      var result = makeConnection(req);
      result.then(value => {
        console.log('result: ' + value);
        if(value == 0)
        {
          console.log('Unknown database!');
          resolve('Unknown database!');
        }
        else if(value == 1)
        {
          console.log('Error trying to connect! Maybe wrong connection data.');
          resolve('Error trying to connect! Maybe wrong connection data.');
        }
        else if(value == 2)
        {
          console.log('Connection Done!');
          resolve('Connection Done!');
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Error handle setDB() results.');
        reject('Error handle setDB() results! Call tech guy.');
      });
    })


    //return connection;
  }
}

function makeConnection(dbname)
{

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    console.log('Start connection....');
    const configs = {
      Emp1: {
        user: "us",
        password: "pass",
        server: "ip",
        database: "Emp1",
        pool: {
          max: 20,
          min: 0,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 900000
        }
      },
      Emp2: {
        user: "us",
        password: "pass",
        server: "ip",
        database: "Emp2",
        pool: {
          max: 20,
          min: 0,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 900000
        }
       }
     };

     var config = configs[dbname];
     if(config == undefined)
     {
       resolve(0);
     }

      global.conn = new mssql.Connection(config);
      conn.connect(function(err)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          resolve(1);
        } else {
          console.log('Database Connected!');
          resolve(2);
        }
      });

  });

}
```

I do this `global.conn = new mssql.Connection(config);` to try to save the connection.

Now if I try to access a link(index) that do a query I have error because `conn is not defined` ...

```
var db = require('../config/db');
var mssql = require('mssql');
var squel = require("squel");
var request = new mssql.Request(conn);
module.exports =
{
  index: (req, res) => {
    console.log("User Index");


    request.query("SELECT * from us",(err, records) => {
      console.log(err);
      //console.log(records);
      res.send(records[0].username);
    });

  }
}
```

I appreciate a lot your opinion about the better way to do this, I don't see much information about multi database connection.
The user has to choose database in login form but after I have to save the database name but how? I already think in cache... I don't know, I need really some advices.

Any doubt about that ask me please.

Thank you